# Routing Error uninitialized constant FavoriteSongsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have Rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.3 ,

Following a tutorial for adding favorites to my existing project, whereby users can favorite property listings but can't get past the error below:

```
Routing Error uninitialized constant FavoriteSongsController
```

[image: screenshot]

favorite_songs_Controller.rb

```
class FavoriteSongsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_song

  def create
    if Favorite.create(favorited: @fav_song, user: current_user)
      flash[:success] = t('favorite_song.success')
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:danger] = t('favorite_song.wrong')
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Favorite.where(favorited_id: @fav_song.id, user_id: current_user.id).first.destroy
    flash[:info] = t('favorite_song.destroy')
    redirect_to :back
  end

   private

  def set_song
    @fav_song = Song.find(params[:song_id] || params[:id])
  end
end
```

songs_controller.rb

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @artist = Artist.friendly.find(params[:artist_id])
    @song = @artist.songs.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

song.rb

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch


  belongs_to :artist
  default_scope -> { order(:title) }

  validates :artist_id, presence: true
  validates :title,     presence: true,
                    length: { maximum: 140 }


  has_attached_file :mp3, 
     :url => "/songs/:artist_slug/:song_slug_:hash.:extension"
  validates_attachment :mp3,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ["audio/mpeg", "audio/mp3"] },
    :file_name => { :matches => [/mp3\Z/] }
  validates_attachment_presence :mp3
  validates_attachment_size :mp3, { less_than: 15.megabytes }

  Paperclip.interpolates :artist_slug do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.artist.slug
  end

  Paperclip.interpolates :song_slug do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.slug
  end

  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
    :hash_secret => "jHLi3fdrmHZQ8r9wxGZbyyGzc9BT8UAxOk2q6O1T1ut+pgmDqmtFIdaBuw8tkhAK0nhDMrCQYCMfOXiUH3R27zG22OHi0852jK93/TaiDtymwzPXZQOxhM6KR6aODhEK+LmqYG1uIGHvqfzD1BOh/R7JuvW2cf+0dT0V3hiFEzA="
  })

  pg_search_scope :search_by_title,
                    :against => :title,
                    :using => {
                      :trigram => {
                        :threshold => 0.1
                      }
                    }

  def slug=(value)
    if value.present?
      write_attribute(:slug, value)
        end
  end

end
```

user.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_songs, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Song'

  validates :email,                   presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                                      email_format: { message: I18n.t('signup.email_invalid') },
                                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password,                    presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 6}


end
```

favorite.rb

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  root 'home#index'
  get 'search', to: 'search#search'


  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup', to: 'users#create'


  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :reset_passwords, only: [:new, :create, :update, :edit]


  resources :artists, :path => "/", only: [:show] do
    resources :songs, :path => "/", only: [:show]
  end

  resources :favorite_songs, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

songs/songs.html.erb

```
    <%= render 'favorite_songs/fav' %>
```

favorite_songs/_fav.html.erb

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <%- unless current_user.favorites.exists?(id: @song.id) -%>
       <%= link_to 'Add to favorites', favorite_songs_path(song_id: @song), method: :post %>
    <%- else -%>
        <%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_song_path(@song), method: :delete %>
    <%- end -%>
<% end %>
```

I've watched various tututorials and followed numerous suggestions but dont seem to be able to solve the issue by myself.

Comment: Is `FavoriteSongsController` defined within `app/controllers/favorite_songs_controller.rb`? Any chance that it's the first controller defined when sorted by name alphabetically?

Comment: name for `favorite_songs_Controller.rb` file should be downcased,please fix it

Comment: @ Anthony E  : sorry, i didn't understand ? FavoriteSongsController is defined . but what have to do with sorting alphabetically

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ: wow that it , it worked now , that was driving me crazy for a week , I wish I had posted problem earlier. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A name for **favorite_songs_Controller.rb** file as well as other files in **app/** folder should be downcased, so please fix it and/or other files too. You can do it as follows from root of your project:

```
find app -type f |while read f; do i=$(tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" <<< $f); mv "$f" "$i" 2>/dev/null; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Your FavoriteSongsController is in `favorite_songs_Controller.rb`.  Ruby will not be able to automatically locate classes in files that do not conform to naming conventions.  You should use `favorite_songs_controller.rb`, instead.  Note the lowercase 'C' in `controller` in the name.  That's what's causing the issue.  Change that and you should be just fine.